# In Presto query how to remove last element of a path

Tags: sql, presto

I have the following url column

```
http://mydomain/user/123 
http://mydomain/subscription/1233 
http://mydomain/user/create
```

What I would like as output using presto query is as below where if it ends with a number it should be removed.

```
http://mydomain/user
http://mydomain/subscription
http://mydomain/user/create
```

I only as able to get up this but it does not give me the required result.

```
SELECT distinct url_extract_host(request_url) as hostname , SUBSTRING(url_extract_path(request_url),1,10) as path
FROM "tk_logs"."servicesjun"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`regexp_replace`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/regexp.html#id2):

```sql
-- sample data
WITH dataset (url) AS (
   VALUES ('http://mydomain/user/123'),
        ('http://mydomain/subscription/1233'),
        ('http://mydomain/user/create'),
        ('http://mydomain/user/122/create'),
        ('http://mydomain/user/122/create/12123'),
        ('http://mydomain/user/122/create/qw12123')
)

-- query
select regexp_replace(trim(url), '(.*)\/([\d]+)$', '$1') url
from dataset
```

Output:

| url |
| --- |
| http://mydomain/user |
| http://mydomain/subscription |
| http://mydomain/user/create |
| http://mydomain/user/122/create |
| http://mydomain/user/122/create |
| http://mydomain/user/122/create/qw12123 |

Regex:

- `(.*)` - 1st capturing group matches any character (except for line terminators) zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
- `\/` - matches the character `/`
- `([\d]+)` - 2nd capturing group - matches digit (`\d`, equivalent to `[0-9]) between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
- `$` asserts position at the end of a line

And replacement - `'$1'` replaces match with first group only